# Does UpdateOne() allow to upsert array with the bucket pattern?

Tags: mongodb

I'm adopting the bucket pattern to store documents in MongoDB. In the documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/data-modeling/design-patterns/group-data/bucket-pattern/#insert-data-with-the-bucket-pattern is indicated that a `$push` can upsert data into an existing array. However it is not clear whether I can push an array and merge the array with the existing one.

Is it something possible?

Comment: Are you asking about [$each](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#mongodb-update-up.-each) modifier?